# Virtual machine crash out and not start in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a problem with Virtual Box, after double clicking it does not start and I do not know how to solve the problem ...

[image]

I was working without problem with the version VirtualBox-5.0.16-105871-Win in Windows 10, when I suddenly stopped working maybe after a windows update, I again ran the Virtual Box installer, the same version and it Click on repair, and nothing ... I do not have a restore point on the computer before the update: / ... I deleted the installed updates and nothing changed ...

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of VirtualBox (5.1.22) and the program starts but when running a virtual machine that I had previously installed it crash out and it does not load, the screen is black with the next white text:

> boot0: GPT
>
> boot0: done_

I have tried modified the configuration from my virtual machine but it is all like before when works correctly.

How I can solve it? Any answer would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't a programming question.

Comment: Anyone know how solve this situation??

Comment: Post this on the right site!  I told you 3 days ago that this question is offtopic. If you would have posted it on Super User 3 days ago, you might have your answer by now.

Comment: I do not know where I must post it ... Super User? What do you refer?

Comment: Yes. It's a sister site to this site.